# Can you get images to display as button in tkinter rather than on the button?

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter

I'm using TKinter to build a GUI for a project I'm doing. I was wondering whether it was possible to get TKinter to display an image *in place of* a button with no border, only the image to be clicked on;
rather than displaying *on top of* the button, with the button border still there which i know could be achieved using code like:

```
photo=PhotoImage(file="add.png")
b = Button(master,image=photo, command=callback, height=50, width=150)
b.pack()
```

which would result in something likewhat is show in [this tutorial](https://pythonspot.com/tk-window-and-button/)

I hope I explained myself clearly; thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a button with no border you can set the border width to 0: `bd=0`. The image will still displace a pixel or so to the down right when you press it.

I that is not good enough you can create a custom button using a Label and bind mouse press and release to that label.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def callback_function():
    print('Button')

# Image button without border
button_img = PhotoImage(file='image_button.png')
b = Button(root, image=button_img, bd=0, command=callback_function)
b.pack(pady=10)

# Custom button using a label
up_img = PhotoImage(file='image_button_up.png')
dn_img = PhotoImage(file='image_button_dn.png')
e = Label(root, image=up_img, bd=0)
e.pack(pady=10)

# Functions for switching images when button is pressed/released
def press(event):
    e.config(image=dn_img)

def release(event):
    e.config(image=up_img)
    callback_function() # Invoke callback function on release

# Bindings for mouse on label
e.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', press)
e.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', release)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Added example for both implementations.